# Why are there no articles before "female membership" and "male control" in this sentence? Is it a mistake?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-article

Did the author make a grammatical error in this sentence?

> "While (***the***) female membership of parliament is the highest in the world (though still far from equal), (***the***) male control of the corporate world is absolute."

Why is there no article before "female" and "male"? I thought the definite article can be used with uncountable nouns?

Comment: For the same reason that we don't need an article before "chocolate cookies" or "rye bread" or "steel girders" when identifying a type or class or category.  We're not referring to something in that category (specific cookies, a particular loaf, a specific set of girders)  but to the category itself.  The author might have needed to use an article there, however.  Can you include the previous sentence?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence as it is.

From what we are taught, we might expect

> **the** female membership of *(British)* parliament

would be appropriate to describe the British situation.  However, use of the article "**the**" also varies between AmE and BrE.

For example, the BBC will report that

> *someone* is in hospital

whereas an AmE speaker will tend to say

> *someone* is in **the** hospital